# Elastic Search combination of with Multiple Range, Term filters with And and Or operators

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a filter with multiple data range filter with And and OR operators. I have to get filter results which satisfies both date range filters or any one of the date range filter.

```
 "query":{
    "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
          "searchField" : {
            "query" : "Adam",
            "slop" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "srvcType" : {
            "value" : "FullTime",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {"range" : { "or": {"startDt": {"from" : "2010-05-16","to" : "2022-02-18","include_lower": true,"include_upper" : true,"boost" : 1.0}} }},
      {"range" : { "or": {"endDt": {"from" : "2015-05-16","to" : "2022-02-18","include_lower" : true,"include_upper" : true,"boost" : 1.0}}}}
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

I tried to run the query like above, I got parsing_exception - query does not support StartDt.

```
{
 "query":{
    "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
          "searchField" : {
            "query" : "Adam",
            "slop" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "srvcType" : {
            "value" : "FullTime",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {"range" : {"startDt": {"from" : "2010-05-16","to" : "2022-02-18","include_lower": true,"include_upper" : true,"boost" : 1.0}} },
      {"range" : {"endDt": {"from" : "2015-05-16","to" : "2022-02-18","include_lower" : true,"include_upper" : true,"boost" : 1.0}}}
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need AND semantics for your date range filters, you can let both `range` queries in the `bool/filter` array.

However, if you need OR semantics you can use the `bool/should` query, like below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "searchField": {
              "query": "Adam",
              "slop": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "srvcType": {
              "value": "FullTime",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startDt": {
              "from": "2010-05-16",
              "to": "2022-02-18",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "endDt": {
              "from": "2015-05-16",
              "to": "2022-02-18",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```